# The difference between wait_queue_head and wait_queue in linux kernel

Tags: linux, queue, wait

I can find many examples regarding `wait_queue_head`.
It works as a signal, create a `wait_queue_head`, someone
can sleep using it until someother kicks it up.

But I can not find a good example of using `wait_queue` itself, supposedly very related to it.

Could someone gives example, or under the hood of them?

Comment: You dont want to give bounty?

Comment: Oh, didn't know I have to click this +50 button. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway!  I have > 3000 :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [Linux Device Drivers](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch05.html):

> The `wait_queue_head_t` type is a fairly simple structure, defined in
>   `<linux/wait.h>`. It contains only a lock variable and a linked list
>   of sleeping processes. The individual data items in the list are of
>   type `wait_queue_t`, and the list is the generic list defined in
>   `<linux/list.h>`.
>
> Normally the `wait_queue_t` structures are allocated on the stack by
>   functions like `interruptible_sleep_on`; the structures end up in the
>   stack because they are simply declared as automatic variables in the
>   relevant functions. In general, the programmer need not deal with
>   them.

Take a look at **A Deeper Look at Wait Queues** part.

> Some advanced applications, however, can require dealing with
>   wait_queue_t variables directly. For these, it's worth a quick look at
>   what actually goes on inside a function like interruptible_sleep_on.
>   The following is a simplified version of the implementation of
>   interruptible_sleep_on to put a process to sleep:
>
> ```
>  void simplified_sleep_on(wait_queue_head_t *queue)
>  {
>    wait_queue_t wait;
>
>    init_waitqueue_entry(&wait, current);
>    current->state = TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE;
>
>    add_wait_queue(queue, &wait);
>    schedule();
>    remove_wait_queue (queue, &wait);
>   }
> ```
>
> The code here creates a new wait_queue_t variable (wait, which gets
>   allocated on the stack) and initializes it. The state of the task is
>   set to TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE, meaning that it is in an interruptible
>   sleep. The wait queue entry is then added to the queue (the
>   wait_queue_head_t * argument). Then schedule is called, which
>   relinquishes the processor to somebody else. schedule returns only
>   when somebody else has woken up the process and set its state to
>   TASK_RUNNING. At that point, the wait queue entry is removed from the
>   queue, and the sleep is done

The internals of the data structures involved in wait queues:

[image]

Update:
for the users who think the image is my own - here is one more time the link to the [Linux Device Drivers](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch05.html) where the image is taken from

Comment: @Tomas - "From your post it is not clear whether you are stil citing or if the image is yours" - Updated my answer

Comment: and wait_queue has changed name to wait_queue_entry.

Answer (score 7):

Wait queue is simply a list of processes and a lock.

`wait_queue_head_t` represents the queue as a whole. It is the head of the waiting queue.

`wait_queue_t` represents the *item* of the list - a single process waiting in the queue.